# Calculating a complex line integral over circle radius 4

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am struggling to come to terms with a method of solving some of the problems in vector analysis regarding complex line integrals. $$\int_{|z|=4} \frac{\sin z}{z} dz,$$ $$\int_{|z|=4} \frac{\sin z}{z-5} dz,$$ $$\int_{|z|=4} \frac{\sin z}{z^2} dz.$$ I assume in some way I am supposed to use Cauchy's integral formula but I am not sure, help appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about where the singularities are in each case with respect to the contour of integration?

Comment: Ok so I find out where the singularities are, so in the first case it would be at $z=0$. Then is it just a case of because this doesn't lie on the circle of radius 4 that I can apply Cauchy's integral formula to get $\frac{2 \pi i}{0!} \sin 0$?

Comment: For the first and third, $z=0$ is still inside your contour (just circle of radius $4$ centered around the origin, right?). For the second one, the only singularity/pole is at $z=5$. Is that in your contour? See here - http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~helena/teaching/math122b/cauchygoursat.pdf and here - http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV4.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first integral, note that $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ has a removable singularity.  Then, from Cauchy's Integral Theorem,

$$\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz=0$$

---

For the second integral, the integrand has a first-order pole at $z=5$. But the region $|z|\le 4$ does not contain $z=5$.  Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees

$$\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-5}\,dz=0$$

---

For the third integral, the integrand has a first-order pole at $z=0$.  Hence, from Cauchy's Integral Formula we have with $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}}{z}\,dz$$

Solving for the integral of interest yields

$$\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\,dz=2\pi i$$